# JAX-WS, date timezone being misinterpreted

Tags: java, datetime, jax-ws

A client of my Web service is sending a date attribute in the following format (ISO):

```
2011-09-12T13:46:00+01:00
```

for a request sent at 13:46, local time (CEST). My Web service (JAX-WS on Glassfish), written as:

```
@WebMethod    
public String getSource(Long id, Date asOfDate) {
    this.log.debug(asOfDate);
    // ...
}
```

interprets as `Mon Sep 12 14:46:00 CEST 2011` (that's the output of the above log command). Why is not interpreted as `Mon Sep 12 13:46:00 CEST 2011`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it doesn't parse the time correctly, but I would try changing the Date parameter to Calendar parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As U Mad said - Date type in Java doesn't have timezone. If you were to start with XML schema for your web service and then used wsimport to generate Java implementation you would notice that it would use XMLCalendar for this (which could be custom mapped to regular Calendar via JAXB if you prefer)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. The JAXB XML file looks as follows:

```xml
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.0" targetNamespace="calendar-schemalet">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:globalBindings>
                <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:dateTime" parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDate" printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDate" />
            </jaxb:globalBindings>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:schema>
```

use command 
wsimport -p <package for generated artifacts> -b .<path of jaxb.xml file>/jaxb.xml   -d <dir where above artifacts will be generated> -a -keep <wsdl url>

Answer (score 0):

But that is the right answer..?

```
2011-09-12T13:46:00+01:00
```

Is 2011-09-12 at 12:46:00 UTC.

Asking for this in CEST (Central European Summer Time, UTC +2 hrs) is:

```
2011-09-12 at 14:46:00
```

Which makes sense.